# In the space of polynomials of degree 2 or less, given the derivative linear transformation D and $T:=1+D+D^2$, $S:=1-D$, show that $S=T^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-fields

Let $ P_2[X] $ be the space of polynomials of degree equal or less than 2 over the field R.
Let:
$$
D: P_2[X] \rightarrow P_2[X]
$$
Be the derivative linear transformation, defined as follows:
$$
(D(P))(X) = P'(X)
$$
Also:
$$
T := 1 + D + D^2
$$

$$
S := 1 - D
$$

Show that $ S = T^{-1} $

Comment: Hint: a direct calculation shows that $ST = TS = 1 - D^3$. What is $D^3f$ for the polynomials $f$ you are interested in?

Comment: To expand on Winther's answer. $D$ is "nilpotent", which is an interesting type of matrix in case you have not read about them so far.

Comment: Please correct me if i'm' wrong: Then that means that D^3 = 0 hence ST=TS=1=I?